# IIS Host Asp.Net MVC application in sub-folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, subdirectory, host

Im trying to host my c# asp.net MVC application under a sub-folder of a drupal website in IIS.

What Im really trying to achieve is the following example
When I access this path www.example.com the drupal website should open and when I access www.example.com/subfolder the MVC application should open

So I have create an application inside the drupal website as in the picture below

[image]

The result is when I access www.example.com/subfolder the default controller and default action is called and the default view for the MVC application shows.
That being said, it does not work for other views.
Whenever I try to access www.example.com/subfolder/Home/SecondAction it just shows a 404 error.
Even if I try access the default view via www.example.com/subfolder/Home/Index does not work and shows 404

I have tried route prefix and route attributes for controller and I have tried these route bindings none of them works

```
//routes.MapRoute(
        //  name: "EDF",
        //  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{edf*}",
        //  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    "SubFolder", // Route name
        //    "EDF/{controller}/{action}",
        //    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
        //    new[] { "EDF.EDF.Controllers" }
        //);

        //  routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "EDF",
        //    url: "EDF/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);


      //  routes.MapRoute(
      //    name: "EDF",
      //    url: "{EDF}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      //    defaults: new { EDF = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      //);
```

> I know some of them does not even make sense but I was desperate at
>   this point and tried everything.

Any idea, suggestion and solution are very appreciated

Comment: The simplest approach is to set up a separate site for that ASP.NET MVC application, and then use ARR with a few rules to bridge the URLs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: I suspect inheritance of configuration, i don't know with drupal how will you handle it to your sub app. But with .net we just clear the config setting we don't want to inherit.

Comment: @LexLi thank you very much. Currently I can not modify the structure to make ARR the main website "example.com" or install new things on it but your suggestion will defiantly help me in future projects.

Comment: @jomsk1e Thank you. Correct but would you please provide me a link or a source to what you do in this scenario. I will try it in case it works for drupal as well.

Comment: Did you enable the url rewrite in the web.config file? If you have enabled the url rewrite rule, please post the url rewrite rule. I guess this may cause your MVC application not work.

Comment: @BrandoZhang Thank you for your response. I have not written any URL rewrite rules and the web.config does not contain any URL rewrite rules.

Comment: Could you please tell me which drupal version you have used now? I will try to search about it, I guess it may contain some route setting.

Comment: @BrandoZhang thanks m8. drupal 7.63, php 7.2.8 
I have searched as well but could not find anything. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Do not need to change your application routes. Add a new website and change physical path to your published files location.

[image: Add New WebSite]

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have done this already. Like I mentioned in the post. It gives 404 whenever I try to access it with controler/action routes. it only works for example.com/subfolder not for example.com/subfolder/Home/index